# Usage of comma after es in " ... ist es..." sentences

Tags: grammar-identification, pronoun

Example 1:

> Nach einem Event ist es nicht erlaubt um Preise zu bitten. [Source-Reverso]

Example 2:

> In Deutschland ist es, anders als z. B. im asiastischen Kulturkreis,.... [Source-My grammar book]

Why did we use a comma in the second sentence but not in the first? Could someone explain the general rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence *should* have a comma.

The dependent clause functions as an object. It's an infinitive clause working as an object clause.
Those can, technically, be "inside":

> ?Nach einem Event ist, um Preise zu bitten, nicht erlaubt.

But this is horrible. Nobody says this. What is done instead is, it is put to start or end:

> **Um Preise zu bitten, ist nach einem Event nicht erlaubt.**
>
> (infinitive clause in first position, then verb)
>
> **Nach einem Event ist nicht erlaubt, um Preise zu bitten.**
>
> (Adverbial "nach einem Event" in first position, then verb)

The **es** refers to the dependent clause, as a placeholder.

> Nach einem Event ist **es** nicht erlaubt, **um Preise zu bitten.**

Usage of **es** depends on the verb and other factors. In your case, it is optional. Also, **es** would not be used if the infinitive clause was at the start. Only at the end, *es* is an option. This is a another big topic and not part of this question.

---

Example 2 is something different.

> In America, red trees are - in comparison to red trees in Germany - larger.

An insertion like above was used, but commata were chosen instead of hyphen.

Comment: You first say, it should have, then later you say it is optional here...?

Comment: @SBrian You misunderstand. The comma is mandatory, the "es" is not.